Can SEO/Google Crawler find the underlying url when I use nextjs Link？
Is Nextjs Link SEO-friendly? Or how should I use it in a SEO friendly way?
I have a bunch of Links in my landing page, and each Link routes to a different page on my website, so it's like <Link href='/california-hotels'> California </Link> <Link href='/new-york-hotels'> New York </Link>
What I really hope for is that Google crawler can discover each of the pages i.e., www.mysite.com/california-hotels www.mysite.com/new-york-hotels I am just unsure if they will be discovered. I am sure if it's a tag, i.e., <a href="www.mysite.com/california-hotels">California</a> it will be no problem because the url is spelled out.
Does the Google crawler have the ability to find the actual url when I use Link? Thank you

In short: yes, Next.js <Link> is SEO-friendly
<Link href="/california-hotels">California</Link>

will be rendered as
<a href="/california-hotels">California</a>

This is perfectly fine for SEO: search engines will see  it as traditonal <a> tag with href attribute. And google crawler is smart enough to understand that href="/california-hotels" and href="www.mysite.com/california-hotels" are the same things (as long as you accessing both from www.mysite.com)

Yes, nextjs behind the scene uses anchor tag only. How can verify it by doing inspect element.
As long as the link is in the DOM, google bot will be able to crawl them.
